# Capturing the return value of cs function through Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I'm badly stuck in this part of my coding where I have to show the user a message that the data has been saved. I have a function in C# , which executes a SQL procedure and returns a value.

C# function:

```
    Sql p = new Sql("Data_Set"); 
    try
    {
        p.Add("plan_table", dt); \\ A temp table 
        p.Run();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/projmain/index.html");
        return "success";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error saving Data <br><hr>" + e.Message + "<br><br>" + e.StackTrace + "<br><br><br><br>" + p.ToString() + "";
    }
}
```

I want to capture the return value in my HTML file where I'm using JsonMethodPost (Java Function). And display a message saying that the data has been saved.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Sql p = new Sql("Data_Set"); 
    try
    {
        p.Add("plan_table", dt); \\ A temp table 
        p.Run();
// heare to put allert message "success"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('success');</script>");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/projmain/index.html"); 
//this code are redirect page 
        return "success"; 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error saving Data <br><hr>" + e.Message + "<br><br>" + e.StackTrace + "<br><br><br><br>" + p.ToString() + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur response. Can you plz let me know if we can have an alert in a cs file to prompt the user? My cleint side is html and java while the server side is cs.

Comment: Response.Write("<script>alert('success');</script>");

Comment: Hi Vivek, I tried this but got an error "The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Use HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('success');</script>");

Comment: I've tried this vivek, but i'm not getting any alert after save.

Comment: use internet explorer browser

Answer (score 0):

If the user is interacting with this function via posting to the server, you can make an ajax call, and on success of that call, display the message. i.e.:

```
jQuery.ajax(url, {
  success: function(data){
  alert("Data saved");
}
```

or something like that.

edit:
You would place this in your index.html, but it sounds like your interacting with the server using java. Not sure how you could wrap that response to the java function in javascript logic that would return a message to the client

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Can you please suggest where should I be using this as I've never used jquery.Should I be using it in the JsonMethodPost? My java fucntion in html file is  "function save" which calls the CS fucntion through JsonMethodPost .  JsonMethodPost("/Modulepath/SaveData", goFunc, "ETable", JSON.stringify(row_array));

Comment: Maybe you could do something like vivek suggested? Send javascript in a script tag in the response

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use jquery to call a c# function and it return the message back. Then you can show this message inside a control like div. Example you have two textboxes and a submit input controls, when it is clicked the jquery calls the c# function. 
Let us have our page html like -

```
        <div id="messageDiv"></div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:-</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="nameInput"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:-</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="emailInput" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The jquery click event of this submit button is given below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitButton").click(function (e) {
            var result = ValidateAll();
            if (result == true) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "yourpage.aspx/yourfunction",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{"name":"' + $("#nameInput").val() + '","email":"' + $("#emailInput").val() + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg.d) {
                            $("#messageDiv").html(msg.d);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (req, status, error) {
                        alert("Error try again");
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Finally your C# function

```
[WebMethod]
public static string yourfunction(string name, string email)
{
    //Insert it to our database
    return "thanks, your message";
}
```

Note that the function should have [WebMethod] attribute and should be static in nature. 
The return value of this C# function is shown inside the div with id 'messageDiv'.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Will try and let you know.